# Саблайн не видит файлы в папках

Tags: css, img

В процессе изучения программирования вылезла следующая проблема: Саблайн не видит в папках (внутри проекта) ни картинок, ни файлов CSS. Как с этим бороться можно? AutoNameFile установлен[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: можешь установить web storm\php storm)
Но что вообще значит "не видит", что Вы под этим имеете в виду? Когда путь пишите? Или слева в эксплорере? Приложите код или скриншоты соответствующие

Comment: Используются теги <img>, <link>, которые должны открывать доступ в текстовом редакторе к файлам. Доступа нет, Саблайн не находит файлы, которые есть в папках. Саму папку находит, а файла в нём нет. И я не могу понять, где косяк

Comment: На счет css файла, то у файла должно быть расширение css, `style.css` и тп, у Вас же файл называется просто `stylecss`.

Comment: Ничего не поменялось, к сожалению. Дальше выбора папки не идёт. То бишь выбираю CSS (папку) и всё, больше ничего не предлагает редактор.

Comment: @reina: что такое "Саблайн" ? o_0

Comment: проблема наверное в каталоге в котором все лежит. в пути присутствует кириллица поэтому возможно и не подхватываются файлы (как вариант)

Comment: C:\Users\Ksana\Desktop\Web\Project\2021\CSS\CSS путь к папке, где лежит файл